# How do you setup local environment variables for Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using http cloud functions to listen for a request and then return a simple message.

I'm developing cloud functions locally using:

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

I've setup some custom environment variables using

```
firebase functions:config:set
```

Accessing the custom config variables using the below code works fine when the project is deployed

```
 functions.config()
```

but it does not work when developing locally. When the function is triggered by hitting: http://localhost:5002/my-project-name/us-central1/functionName I can't access the custom config variables. when using functions.config() locally, I can see the default config, just not my custom config variables

Is there an alternate solution or best practice for environment variables when working locally?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're doing when you say that you're developing locally?

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the question. Hopefully that provides a bit more clarity about what I'm doing

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  I'll file a bug internally on this (I'm with the Firebase team).  Feel free to also leave a bug report at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Answer (score 159):

As of now, you have to manually create a `.runtimeconfig.json` file **inside your functions directory** by running this command. Then run the serve command.

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

If you are using Windows Powershell, replace the above with:

```
firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json
```

You can learn more in https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: Could you detail the local config set in order to test function that send FCM notifications ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special. The emulator automatically populates functions.config().firebase with the right project credentials. So the following lines will work locally: const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

Comment: And here's the code sample for using FCM within a function: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

Comment: My trigger launch a FCM notificatin on User Creation. it works on Firebase server but tested locally I have the error : "info: Function crashed
{ Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenti
cate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. R
aw server response: "<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
". Status code: 401."

Comment: Oh interesting, can you file a bug to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues, and follow the template to add repro instructions? Thanks!

Comment: Works march 4, 2018 ty!

Comment: Slight note here that the json file referenced above has to be in your `functions` directory like the post mentioned, so just running the above snipped w/o being in the functions directory first (say if you're in the root of the firebase proj instead) won't work. In that case, you'd have to run something like `firebase functions:config:get > functions/.runtimeconfig.json` instead.

Comment: Not working for me. I have the ".runtimeconfig.json" in the "functions" dir generated with "functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json". But when I am in localhost and execute "functions.config()" in my project it returns an empty object.

Comment: In Windows you must exec: firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json

Comment: This is also noted in the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache did you figure out why it was returning an empty object? I'm having the same issue because whenever I run `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` on Mac it actually replaces all of the data in that file with an empty JSON object... I tried it with different filenames like `.devConfig.json` and `.serveConfig.json`, but whatever filename I provide in the command gets overwritten with an empty JSON object..

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache I also get this result (empty dictionary). Any thoughts on how to solve?

Answer (score 16):

For those who want to use the environment variables (process.env), I follow this workaround.

Set the config values before deploying

```sh
firebase functions:config:set envs.db_host=$DB_HOST_PROD envs.db_user=$DB_USER_PROD envs.db_password=$DB_PASSWORD_PROD envs.db_name=$DB_NAME_PROD envs.db_use_ssl=false
```

Read the config and update the env variables first thing under your functions code.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const config = functions.config();

// Porting envs from firebase config
for (const key in config.envs) {
    process.env[key.toUpperCase()] = config.envs[key];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can keep a file called .env.json and load it when you trigger deploy command

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "npm run env && firebase deploy --only functions",
    "env": "test -f env.json && firebase functions:config:unset env && firebase functions:config:set env=\"$(cat env.json)\" || echo \"Please add the file env.json before deploy.\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've narrowed down the issue to Windows Powershell.

Running `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` in powershell generates a broken json I don't know why, which when parsed gives Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0.

I've managed to sort it out by running .runtimeconfig.json generation command in Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Nrwl NX](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/836), you will have to generate your `.runtimeconfig.json` inside of the `dist/apps/functions` directory.

Example `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "firebase:emulators:start": "firebase functions:config:get > dist/apps/functions/.runtimeconfig.json && env-cmd firebase emulators:start --export-on-exit=\".firebase-emulator\" --import=\".firebase-emulator\""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the top-rated answer works or not but for firebase function on mac (to-serve locally), I do something like this

```
npm run admin-keys && export dev=true && firebase emulators:start
```

Where admin keys is

```
"admin-keys": "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='./.keys/admin.keys.json'"
```

This will load configuration from `.runtimeconfig.json`

For production, you would manually have to set it by doing something like this

```
firebase functions:config:set facebookCred.secret="something"
```