# how to get/set firebase cloud functions v1 environment variables

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was using the environment variables from Cloud Functions package the old way by using the `functions.config()` command, but since I updated to v1.0.2 I cannot use the env variables even through `JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)` like the documentation tells to do, and I couldn't find how to set or get other information. This command only gives me information about the project but not the information I have set using the old approach. How can I get/set this information using the new approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You still access environment variables set by the Firebase CLI using `functions.config()`.  That hasn't changed at all.  There is just no longer a `functions.config().firebase`.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the documentation. Do you want to write the same thing as an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer?
Thank you very much for the heads up again, Doug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for the environment changes in 1.0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#functionsconfigfirebase_removed) can be a little confusing.  functions.config() isn't going away - you still use that to access environment variables that you set using the Firebase CLI with `firebase functions:config:set`.  The things that changed with respect to configuration are the following:

- `functions.config().firebase` is no longer used for project configuration.  That information is now stored in the process environment as `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG`.
- You can now initialize the Admin SDK with no arguments as `admin.initializeApp()`.  The configuration will be picked up from the Cloud Functions runtime automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So check out this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45064266/4871483. What I understand is that the new cloud functions will work from a local `.runtimeconfig.json`. What I would recommend is temporarily downgrade and write your old config to that file. Then you can use these docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator for the code on how to access it once you upgrade again.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not what I meant. I misunderstood the documentation by thinking that the `functions.config()` method was not working anymore.
I should not have changed the approach for getting my custom information.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll leave the answer up there if anyone else needs to do the migration or local environment variables

Answer (score 0):

What I do is basically have

```
env.prod.ts
env.dev.ts
env.ts
```

and in env.ts I  do

```
export const env = require(`./env.${functions.config().env.name}').default;
```

and in package.json i set

```
"dev-prod": firebase use prod && functions:config:set env.name=prod
```

etc
so I can have both fb keys and my own prod keys and the whole app is config-agnostic

when i need env var I just use

```
import environment from '../env.ts'
```

works with json etc(dotenv doesnt)