# Setting Firebase environment variables

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have used Heroku and Netlify for storing Firebase environment variables, and it seems pretty straightforward as I can go to the website and enter them manually. I was looking around Firebase and it seems a little more complicated. Where does everyone go to for setting environment variables for Firebase? Is there a sure fire way to do it on the website by just entering in the values? I'm currently messing around with create-react-app.

Comment: Unlike Heroku - there is no way to enter/view environment variables on the website. They have to be configured using the command line. Word of warning - make sure you're following the [v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139495/how-to-get-set-firebase-cloud-functions-v1-environment-variables) format and not the outdated beta format when you're looking at examples.

Comment: What is a "Firebase environment variable"?  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Which Firebase product are you trying to use?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I meant environment variables in general such as api keys for example.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little after the fact but you set firebase environment variables from the command line using

```
firebase functions:config:set someObject.key1="www.api.com" someObject.key2="someOtherKey"
```

then access them using the firebase-functions npm package

```
var api = functions.config().someObject.key1;
```

I will happily admit it's nowhere near as simple as the way Heroku/Amazon do it where they just append variables to process.ENV and it can all be configured from a UI

Comment: Hey, I know this is a long time after your post but I'm still really flummoxed. Am I right in thinking we can no longer simply use ```REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY=xxx``` in our .env file? I've been trying, like with Netlify, but my hosted app seems to work for a short time and then stop working.