# Setting up dotenv in firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to move the tiny node-express app I made into Firebase functions.

The files have **`dotenv`** variables. Earlier I thought If I just deployed and put the dotenv in dependency, It would work but that didn't happen so...

So, I went to the environment configuration article of Firebase [to understand how I can set .env](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)

Which states to set things by doing something like this

```
firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

But I have so many environment configurations and doing that some what seems to be a cumbersome task.

So let's say this is an environment file

```
# App port Address
PORT = 8080

# Google Secret 
GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL =   http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 40xxxx8-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = lxxxxxxxxxxxxO

# Client Address 
CLIENT_ADDRESS = http://localhost:3000/


# Meetup Secret 
MEETUP_CALLBACK_URL = http://localhost:8080/auth/meetup/callback
MEETUP_CLIENT_ID = exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt
MEETUP_CLIENT_SECRET = sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt

#EventBrite Secret 
EVENTBRITE_CALLBACK_URL = http://localhost:8080/auth/eventbrite/callback
EVENTBRITE_CLIENT_ID = UxxxxxxxxxxxxxN
EVENTBRITE_CLIENT_SECRET = Nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4
```

How Can I best set up so that when I do firebase **firebase serve --only functions,hosting** it doesn't throw any errors such as

> OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase CLI currently doesn't allow you to set process environment variables on deployment.  This may change in the future.  The configuration vars it supports today (that you linked to) are not actually process environment variables - they stored somewhere else that's not actually the process environment.

If you absolutely need to be able to set process environment variables, you will have to deploy your function with gcloud, which means that you also won't be able to use the firebase-functions module to define your function.  Start with the [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) documentation to learn about deployment from a Cloud perspective.

If you want to use the Firebase tools, I'd recommend that you find a different way to configure your function that doesn't involve process environment variables.

Answer (score 27):

As of **Feb 16, 2022** Firebase now supports `.env`, `.env.prod`, `.env.dev`, `.env.local` files natively!

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Set your variables in the corresponding environment, and then run `firebase use dev` or `firebase use prod` before you deploy.

Your variables can be accessed via `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: Amazing new feature! One gotchya - I needed to have an .env.local when using the local emulators. I just wasted an hour thinking it wasn't working when I just didn't have this file. I also recommend the new $ firebase functions:config:export command to download your existing environment through firebase-tools.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED 2019-06-04**

I'm very sorry. This solution is wrong.

I found the correct way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45064266/1872674

You should put a `.runtimeconfig.json` into the functions directory. Your dotenv variables move to `.runtimeconfig.json` with json format.

---

This is my solution.

```
const functionConfig = () => {
    if (process.env.RUN_LOCALLY) {
        const fs = require('fs');
        return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('.env.json'));
    } else {
      return functions.config();
    }
};
```

The `functionConfig()` was called by your Firebase Function.

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("someservice id is: " + functionConfig().someservice.id);
});
```

`.env.json` is like:

```
{
  "someservice": {
    "key":"THE API KEY",
    "id":"THE CLIENT ID"
  }
}
```

Finally, run the command with the `RUN_LOCALLY` variable.

```
RUN_LOCALLY=1 firebase serve
```

When we will deploy functions,
don't forget to update the environment configuration in Firebase using the `.env.json`.

Comment: See the answer from @d-_-b which is more up to date

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have your functions use the process.env variables, you you can set them by going to google cloud console and cloud functions. You will be able to find the deployed firebase functions there. You can select each function one by one and then set the environment variables there.

Answer (score 2):

what I did was create a env.json file into functions FOLDER:

```
//env.json
{
   "send_email_config": {
       "FOW_ADMIN_EMAIL": "admin.example@gmail.com",
       "FOW_ADMIN_EMAIL_PASSWORD": "adminPassExample",
       "FOW_ADMIN_RECEIVER_EMAIL": "adminReceiver.example@gmail.com"
   }
}
```

then I created a file called env.js where I created a function to return the value of functions.config() which is kind of env module

```
//env.js
// TO UPDATE functions.config().env RUN INSIDE functions FOLDER: 
// firebase functions:config:set env="$(cat env.json)" 

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const getEnvConfig = () => {
    /* 
       I return functions.config().env cause I set the env.json values into env 
       property running firebase functions:config:set env="$(cat env.json)"
    */
    return functions.config().env
}

exports.getEnvConfig = getEnvConfig;

exports.PROCESS_ENV = getEnvConfig();
```

then I just call PROCESS_ENV to access the values that I set on env.json file for example:

```
const { PROCESS_ENV } = require('./utils/env');

exports.mailCredentials = {
    main: {
        email: PROCESS_ENV.send_email_config.FOW_ADMIN_EMAIL,
        password: PROCESS_ENV.send_email_config.FOW_ADMIN_EMAIL_PASSWORD
    },
    receiver: {
        email: PROCESS_ENV.send_email_config.FOW_ADMIN_RECEIVER_EMAIL
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT!!!!**

for this to work you have to deploy functions.config().env with the values of the env.json file

to deploy functions.config().env you just have to run INSIDE the functions FOLDER the next command: **firebase functions:config:set env="$(cat env.json)"**

and also don't forget to add env.json in your **.gitignore**

if you have firebase functions FOLDER inside your react project just add ***/env.json** into your react **.gitignore** file

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Answer (score 0):

your .env file need to be in the "functions" folder

Here you have the documentation about this

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

you can access variables like this :

This is your .env :

```
PLANET=Earth
AUDIENCE=Humans
```

and a firebase functions

```
// Responds with "Hello Earth and Humans"
exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send(`Hello ${process.env.PLANET} and ${process.env.AUDIENCE}`);
});
```

For your local environment you can have a .env.local file and  the contents of .env.local take precedence over .env when you are using the emulators suite

Comment: thanks for that : your .env file need to be in the "functions" folder

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `env` to store secrets as it is plainly visible in the deployed code in Firebase. Use environment_configuration instead.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=1st#environment_configuration

Comment: Where in the code is this secret visible? Someone was able to access my API KEY which is in an .env file which has not been uploaded to source control (it is in gitignore) no one but me has access to my Firebase app. I am using Node for Firebase functions. Even every time I change the API KEY it is of no use because they can continue using it.