# Firebase Functions environment variables

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So i was migrating my app from node express to firebase-functions!

In my node-express app I have .env file which contains all the data, FOr starters let's consider this as my .env file

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 4046108-bssbfjohpj94l0dhpu69vpgs1ne0.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = lTQHpj3yY57oQpO
```

And then in my passport strategy, I have something like this

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL:  "/auth/google/callback",
    userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
    accessType: 'offline',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
```

Now,

**Question: 1** - Firebase-functions probably don't support .env file, so can we set env variable without manually adding it using set flag? let's say I have lot variable in my environment

**Question - 2:** Can I access the variable I set by doing something like this

```
firebase functions:config:set slack.url=https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX
```

using

```
 process.env.slack.url
```

or we have to do (necessary)

```
functions.config().slack.url
```

**Question:3** From [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), it is written

> There are environment variables that are automatically populated in
>   the functions runtime and in locally emulated functions, including:
>
> process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT: Provides the Firebase project ID
>
> process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG: Provides the following Firebase project
>   config info:

What do they mean when they mean? and if the answer to the question two is false then how are they using   `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG:`

Comment: Is this a real google-client-id/secret? If so, consider removing it

Comment: @jo_va Secret/Client-ID won't work for others. I randomly removed Alphabets/numbers from between. Btw- Can you answer the question?

Comment: You're confusing process environment variables, and the special environment configuration provided by the Firebase tools.  They're completely different things.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you help me in comprehending the difference between both? I wasn't able to understand the difference between both from firebase docs.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer for question 1:

Please note that, at this time, there doesn't appear to be a supported way to deploy true environment variables along with your function(s) using the firebase CLI tool. You can instead provide it as `function.config()` information, which is their recommended alternative to environment variables.

If you really really want to avoid function config, "pure" google cloud functions support setting environment variables. [This page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) is a walkthrough of how to use a .env.yaml file and ultimately access those values from process.env in your code base. I know your file wasn't *.yaml, but this is a good solution (with some minor refactoring to YAML format).

The short version:

`gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --env-vars-file .env.yaml FLAGS`

### Answer for question 2

There is a difference between Firebase function config key/value pairs (i.e. `function.config()`) and `process.env` access. They are similar in purpose, but persist data in different places (i.e. in Firebase's services vs actual environment variables). Thus, the syntax for accessing each one is different.

### Answer for question 3

Firebase has some `process.env` variables available to you by convention. They're simply documenting that for your convenience, so you can assume those are there and available as true environment variables (and not `function.config()` values).

Again, as of right now, the CLI tool doesn't seem to let you set true environment variables. So you'll have to go with function config, or do some other hack similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55974919/4161426), which takes your function config key/values and sets them as environment variables at runtime.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const config = functions.config();
// Porting envs from firebase config
for (const key in config.envs){
  process.env[key.toUpperCase()] = config.envs[key];
}
```

Comment: I've used this. `firebase functions:config:set service_account="$(cat service-account.json)"` It could be added to Node's scripts or a `.yml` I think.

Answer (score 3):

There's a better way as of **Feb 16, 2022**: Firebase now supports `.env`, `.env.prod`, `.env.dev` files natively!

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

You can create your env files and then use `firebase use dev` or `firebase use prod` before you deploy.

These variables can be accessed via `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: These values are only accessible during development though otherwise you would have secrets in your deployment pipeline right?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a need for this and came to a different solution than what was provided here.

First, there are a lot of discussions about why you should separate secrets from configuration. Firebase allows us to do that with the `.env`, `.env.local`, `.env.dev`, etc files. It is a best practice to store configuration here, not secrets.

Straight from their docs

> Environment variables stored in .env files can be used for function configuration, but you should not consider them a secure way to store sensitive information such as database credentials or API keys. This is especially important if you check your .env files into source control.

What hasn't been discussed is how to store secrets. The values from the OP appear to be secrets and not configuration so in my opinion this is a relevant addition to this question.

Firebase functions have access to [Cloud Secret Manager](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret-manager).

> To help you store sensitive configuration information, Cloud Functions for Firebase integrates with Google Cloud Secret Manager. This encrypted service stores configuration values securely, while still allowing easy access from your functions when needed.

You can import `runWith` and `defineSecret` to define and access your secret.

```
import { runWith } from 'firebase-functions/v1';
import { defineSecret } from 'firebase-functions/params';

const secretApiKey = defineSecret('MY_API_KEY');

const functionName = runWith({ secrets: [secretApiKey] })

  // ...
  client.setApiKey(process.env.MY_API_KEY);
  // ...

export default functionName;
```

This works with https functions, as well as auth, storage, and firebase triggers.

```
const onFirestore = runWith({ secrets: [secretApiKey] })
  .firestore.document('/the/{docId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {

const onStorage = runWith({ secrets: [secretApiKey] })
  .storage().bucket().object()
  .onCreate(async (object) => {
```

Some note worthy caveats

The service account deploying the function needs the secret manager admin role.

> Whenever you set a new value for a secret, you must redeploy all functions that reference that secret for them to pick up the latest value.

> If you delete a secret, make sure that none of your deployed functions references that secret. Functions that use a secret value that has been deleted will fail silently.

Answer (score 1):

## Reminder

Unlike `dotenv` Firebase environment files should start with `.env`.

So, `file.env` will have to be named be `.env.file` for it to work in firebase functions.