# import env variables from file in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I know we can set env variables in command line like this:

```
firebase functions:config:set slack.id="XXXX" slack.secret="XXXX"
```

But if we have too many env variables to set, can we put it in a file and import like this:

```
firebase functions:config:set env_variables.json
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI does not have an option for this.  What you can do instead is write a script to parse that JSON file and convert that into multiple arguments to pass to the CLI as needed.

You are also free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Answer (score 1):

At this moment it is not possible to put in a file your variables and import it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775691/firebase-functions-environment-variables) you can find an explained answer about this. I think it could be helpful for you.