# Firebase Cloud Functions runtimeconfig invalid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Setting up the cloud functions emulator required me to export my environment variables. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_functions_configuration_optional) says to run the below command (powershell) in the functions dir:

```
firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json
```

Now the emulator gives me a warning:

```
!  Found .runtimeconfig.json but the JSON format is invalid.
```

This is .runtimeconfig.json

```
{
  "slack": {
    "moulding": "<URL>"
  },
  "email": {
    "address": "<MY_EMAIL>",
    "password": "<PASSWORD>"
  }
}
```

How can I solve this? I'm not sure how the format is invalid since the CLI generated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766536/how-do-you-setup-local-environment-variables-for-cloud-functions-for-firebase), someone suggested to use the below command in Command Prompt in the `functions` dir instead of Powershell

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

Not sure why the above works, but it does